# Visual Studio 2019 Toolbar - Change Element Display Size

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019, how can I resize the toolbar control elements to make them longer or shorter?

For example, the *Solution Configuration* and *Solution Platform* dropdown displays are too short and too long respectively to fit all the text (see picture).

[image: Screenshot of visual studio toolbar]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can go to VS toolbar customization, click **Modify Selection** and adjust the **Width** value:

[image]